# Entity-Framework 6, defining relationship by two IDs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Context: I have to change a part of a Model from a single value to a List of entries and need help defining the relationship between the two classes.

The Model *(simplified)* looks like this:

```
public class Settings {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public Guid NodeId { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

  // plus the respective virtual properties and a few more irrelevant things.
}
```

Now the relationship has changed so that I have to handle multiple Templates, plus a few new flags, to something like this:

```
public class Settings {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid NodeId { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public ICollection<TemplateConfig> Configs { get; set; }
  // ...
}

public class TemplateConfig {
  public Guid NodeId { get; set; }
  public Guid UserId { get; set; }
  public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }
  // and a few more flags
}

builder.Entity<TemplateConfig>().HasKey(t => new { t.NodeId, t.UserId, t.TemplateId });
```

Since many of my access will be directly on this list and based on either all entries for a Node, a User or a Template, I don't mind the redundancy in the IDs, Actually I prefer it.

I'd like to **not** have to add a `SettingsId` just to be able to define this relationship, but rather do something like this:

```
builder.Entity<Settings>()
       .HasMany(s => s.Configs)
       .HasForeignKey(s => new {s.NodeId, s.UserId});
```

So based on the shared ID-pair `NodeId, UserId`.

But my EF knowledge is still very limited.

I've tried it through the `DbModelBuilder` and through `ForeignKey` and `Column`-attributes. Different errors; all boiling down to a mismatch in the number of IDs between the Principal and the Dependant in the relationship.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It does not matter whether you configure EF through attributes, conventions or fluent API. All three means are nearly equal in power with fluent API being the most expressive of all. Related to topic at hand, are you getting any error if you configure FK like you have shown?

Comment: @TanveerBadar the fluent API requires me to define the other direction too `.HasMany(s => s.Configs).WithRequired(c => c.Setting).HasForeignKey(...)`. Added a virtual prop for this but still got the error `The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `Settings` class has a single column primary key  `public Guid Id { get; set; }`. when you define relationship, EF core tries to bind 2 column foreign key .`HasForeignKey(s => new {s.NodeId, s.UserId});` to 1 column primary key of `'Settings'` which is not possible. But you can tell EF to bind a foreign key to different columns which are called "Principal Key". Try adding `.WithPrincipal()` in your code like this:

```
 builder.Entity<Settings>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Configs)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(c => new {c.NodeId, c.UserId})
            .HasPrincipalKey(s => new {s.NodeId, s.UserId});
```

### **Answer for EF 6**:

Since EF 6 does not have `.HasPrincipalKey()`, the principal columns should be specified with `.Map()`:

```
builder.Entity<Settings>()
        .HasMany(s => s.Configs)
        .WithOne()
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("NodeId", "UserId");
                cs.MapRightKey("NodeId", "UserId");
            });
```

Comment: Sadly we're still running EF6 in this project and these methods are not available. Still, thank you.

Comment: No luck either. Neither `WithOne()` is available, nor does `Map()` provide `MapLeftKey` or `MapRightKey`. Did a bit more reading, it seems that I can't solve this with my current EF version. Nonetheless it was very educative and I'll revisit this answer when we update EF.